# Cannot create an ad or ad creative via the facebook API

Tags: laravel, facebook, api, sdk

So I'm working on a project from work using the facebook API so we can build ads (yes I know you can do it from facebook ads manager but my company wants me to create our own interface).  Anyways so I'm able to create campaigns and ad sets through the API but I cannot seem to have any luck with ads and or creatives.

```
{message: "Invalid parameter", exception: "FacebookAds\Http\Exception\AuthorizationException",…}
exception
:
"FacebookAds\Http\Exception\AuthorizationException"
file
:
"/Users/bradgoldsmith/Desktop/SquibLib/vendor/facebook/php-ads-sdk/src/FacebookAds/Http/Exception/RequestException.php"
line
:
144
message
:
"Invalid parameter"
trace
:
[{,…}, {,…},…]
```

That's the error I seem to get and from the looks it has something to do with Authorization but I'm able to create campaigns and ad sets so I figured I'm authorized.  I'm just testing dummy data on a page that I am an admin on.  Any advice or pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

So turns out the authorization issue has something to do with the fact that our app is still in review.  I was able to however create a carousel ad/ad creative through their API with this bit of code, which I also got from their documentation.  Anyways the code that worked for me is here:

```
    $product1 = (new AdCreativeLinkDataChildAttachment())->setData(array(
  AdCreativeLinkDataChildAttachmentFields::LINK =>
    'https://www.link.com/product1',
  AdCreativeLinkDataChildAttachmentFields::NAME => 'Product 1',
  AdCreativeLinkDataChildAttachmentFields::DESCRIPTION => '$8.99',
  AdCreativeLinkDataChildAttachmentFields::IMAGE_HASH => '<IMAGE_HASH>',
));

$product2 = (new AdCreativeLinkDataChildAttachment())->setData(array(
  AdCreativeLinkDataChildAttachmentFields::LINK =>
    'https://www.link.com/product2',
  AdCreativeLinkDataChildAttachmentFields::NAME => 'Product 2',
  AdCreativeLinkDataChildAttachmentFields::DESCRIPTION => '$9.99',
  AdCreativeLinkDataChildAttachmentFields::IMAGE_HASH => '<IMAGE_HASH>',
));

$product3 = (new AdCreativeLinkDataChildAttachment())->setData(array(
  AdCreativeLinkDataChildAttachmentFields::LINK =>
    'https://www.link.com/product3',
  AdCreativeLinkDataChildAttachmentFields::NAME => 'Product 3',
  AdCreativeLinkDataChildAttachmentFields::DESCRIPTION => '$10.99',
  AdCreativeLinkDataChildAttachmentFields::IMAGE_HASH => '<IMAGE_HASH>',
));

$link_data = new AdCreativeLinkData();
$link_data->setData(array(
  AdCreativeLinkDataFields::LINK => '<URL>',
  AdCreativeLinkDataFields::CHILD_ATTACHMENTS => array(
    $product1, $product2, $product3,
  ),
));

$object_story_spec = new AdCreativeObjectStorySpec();
$object_story_spec->setData(array(
  AdCreativeObjectStorySpecFields::PAGE_ID => <PAGE_ID>,
  AdCreativeObjectStorySpecFields::LINK_DATA => $link_data,
));

$creative = new AdCreative(null, 'act_<AD_ACCOUNT_ID>');
$creative->setData(array(
  AdCreativeFields::NAME => 'Sample Creative',
  AdCreativeFields::OBJECT_STORY_SPEC => $object_story_spec,
));

$creative->create();
```